# How to resolve org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException in Http Request to another server?

Tags: java

I am using HttpClient to handling http requests and when I try to contect with my target server I am getting a error as

```
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to prdalonegk.alonegk.com:9090 timed out
```

where `prdalonegk.alonegk.com:9090` is my xmpp server

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: You cannot resolve it if its genuinely not able to connect - check whether that server accepts HTTP connection and is available

Comment: Fix your network, or firewall, or the target server, or increase the timeout value. It's not a coding problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the host `prdalonegk.alonegk.com` is reacheable

```
ping prdalonegk.alonegk.com
```

and that it is can accept connections on port `9090` (firewall).

If all is ok, then try to increase the connection timeout:

```
RequestConfig.Builder requestBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setConnectTimeout(3000L); /* in ms */
```

Please refere to the [request builder javadocs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html) for all the settings you may provide.